# Orchard CMS: Can I use Amazon S3 service as source for Media Library?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, orchardcms

I want to store site images in Amazon S3 service. How can I manage (upload/delete/use) these files by Orchard CMS Media Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement an `IStorageProvider` that will use Amazon S3 service under the hood. There are a few implementations already available - just google it.

If you want an example, please take a look at how it's done in `Orchard.Azure` module. `AzureBlobStorageProvider` uses Azure Blob storage for the very same thing.

Comment: I implemented and published module Amazon S3 module : http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Amba.AmazonS3